# How can I associate custom properties to an Angular Material component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I create N expansion panels when my form is loaded and the first panel is left open by default.  Each panel has its own formGroup with N controls.

When the user tries to save the form I mark all controls on the form as touched so that validation fires and invalid controls are highlighted.  I then want to open up all panels that contain invalid controls and close all those that do not contain controls with validation errors.

I tried playing around with the expanded property in the template but that appears to be evaluated only when the form is loaded and is not maintained after the user starts to manually open and close panels (which makes sense).

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="i == 0"
     *ngFor="let p of panels; let i=index" 
     formGroupName="{{ p.formGroupName }}"
     [attr.data-valid]="this.form.get(p.formGroupName).valid">

... some form controls ...

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

I was hoping to be able to set the data-valid property, as shown above, so that I can just iterate all MatExpansionPanels and set the expanded property accordingly.  However, dataset is not available to me when I use the following.

```
  @ViewChildren(MatExpansionPanel) panels: QueryList<MatExpansionPanel>;
```

I could find a match between panel and formGroup by parsing the number from the end of the id property of the MatExpansionPanel instance but I suspect I shouldn't be making any assumptions about this value.

Once I have a MatExpansionPanel instance using ViewChildren I don't see how to get the nativeElement so that I can get to the dataset.  If I query for nativeElements I then don't have access to the MatExpansionPanel.  What to do?

Comment: Please stop rolling back the edits on this post; these edits make no sense unless you are just trying to bump the post. Please only edit your post to correct errors, to include additional insights or to update the question for changing circumstances. See [How do I get attention for old, unanswered questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions)

Comment: It was hardly deliberate.  I’ve never undone an edit before, it wasn’t so intuitive.  The real inconvenience was the first edit, which added no value to the question.

Comment: Actually, the first edit was (largely) appropriate. It corrected your use of an incorrect tag. And "rolling back" to a previous edit should only be done once. Your edit history looks like v1 = original, v2 = edit, v3 = RB to v1, v4 = RB to v2, v5 = RB to v3, v6 = RB to v4, v7 = RB to v5. The net effect was that versions 7 and 1 are identical; revisions 4 through 7 were completely unnecessary.

Comment: Ed, you lost me at ‘Actually’.  Did I mention the extra edits were unintentional and that I found the UI confusing? Looking forward to an edit/comment that makes a technical contribution.

Comment: I was responding to your claim that “the first edit ... added no value to the question.” In any case, you might want to read about [how editing works here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to avoid similar errors in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do something like this:
At first enable multiple opened panels with

```html
<mat-accordion [multi]="true"></mat-accordion>
```

then pass the valid flag of the formGroup directly the the `expanded` input in addition with a flag.

```html
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="this.form.get(p.formGroupName).valid && flag">
  [...]
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Afterwards set the `flag` as true, when you submit the form and set the flag as false by default and when the form gets *dirty*.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I described a use case to give context to my question.  I solved the particular use case long ago but I never did figure out how to associate custom properties with material controls.